# Open subgroups of the etale fundamental group of $P^1_\mathbb Q\setminus\{0,\infty\}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-cohomology, profinite-groups, galois-groups

Let $G$ be the etale fundamental group of $P^1_\mathbb Q\setminus\{0,\infty\}$. Then $G$ is isomorphic to a semidirect product of $\widehat  {\mathbb Z}(1)$ by $ Gal_\mathbb Q$.

Is it true that every open subgroups of $G$ splits as a semidirect product of  $\widehat  {\mathbb Z}(1)$ by $ Gal_K$ for some finte extension $K$ of $\mathbb Q$?

In general, is there a nice description of the extensions $U$:

$$1\to \widehat  {\mathbb Z}(1)\to U\to Gal_K\to 1?$$

Answer (score 2):

The first question seem OK. Here is a sketch. I might have overlooked something.

If $H\subset G$ is an open subgroup, then the image
of $H$ in $Gal_\mathbb{Q}$ is open so necessarily of the form $Gal_K$. So we get an extension
$$1\to H\cap \hat{\mathbb{Z}}\to H\to Gal_K\to 1$$
The kernel $ H\cap \hat{\mathbb{Z}}\subset \hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is closed and of finite index, so it is   $N\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ for some integer $N>0$.

Let $H'\subset G$ be the preimage $Gal_K$. The kernel of $H'\to Gal_K$ is $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$. We have that $H\subset H'$ and $H\cap \ker(H\to Gal_K) = N\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$. We can identify $H'=\pi_1^{et}(\mathbb{G}_{m,K})$. Let $H''\subset H'$ be the subgroup corresponding to the étale cover $\mathbb{G}_{m,K}\to \mathbb{G}_{m,K}$ given by multiplication by $N$.
As a  subgroup $H\subset H'$ coincides with $H''$. Thus
$H\cong \pi_1^{et}(\mathbb{G}_{m,K})$ which a semi direct product of $Gal_K$ with 
$\hat{\mathbb{Z}}(1)$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please explain  why $H^{\prime\prime}$ and $H$ should coincide. In fact, I do not see  why they are conjugated.

Comment: @Donu: I don't understand what do you mean by "The kernel of $H\rightarrow \mathrm{Gal}_K$ is $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$" indeed, one line above you wrote this kernel as $N\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$. I agree this is isomorphic to $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$, but are you claiming $N=1$? In fact, I do not understand if the OP would like that every open subgroup contains the whole $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}(1)$ or something isomorphic to it.

Comment: Andrei: I'll expand when I have more time. Filippo: There was a typo, which I fixed. I understood that he meant the latter, otherwise it's false ($N$ need not be $1$).

Comment: @FilippoAlbertoEdoardo: I do not want $N$ to be 1. I meant that $\widehat{\mathbb Z}(1)$ and $N\widehat{\mathbb Z}(1)$ are isomorphic as $Gal_K$-modules.